# Does redirecting prevent users from accessing files in the root?

Tags: php, security, environment-variables, web-hosting

Hey everyone I'm publishing my website and I want to make it as secures as i can.
I have researched if storing API keys and database credentials in php is safe.
I read about the suggestion of storing them for example in a .env file outside of the root.
I was checking my webhosting but I don't have the option of posting them outside the root.
The website now redirects to a folder with all the files and i stored the .env outside of it.

Is the .env file still accessible by users in the public after redirecting?

I would love to get an answer or suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Comment: If your host doesn't support something you believe to be a good security practice, I'd move if I were you. Hosting is pretty cheap these days. But I understand if that's not an option. `.env` files aren't magical and aren't secure/insecure, they are just a common pattern for storing things. If you can't make an HTTP request that successfully accesses such a file, then you have secured that file, although there's always a question if you've accounted for every URL variation which is why most people move them out of root (and guard against path traversal attacks).

Comment: What sort of server is it?  If it's apache style then you should .htaccess file to secure it.